# Historical changes from 'not yet' to 'not again' and vice-versa

Tags: historical-linguistics, pragmatics, negation

A two part question. Are there attested historical changes whereby a construction **C** in some language means 'not yet', and then **C** changes in meaning so that it means 'not again' at a later time (or vice versa)? Second, can someone situate such an alternation, real or imagined, within some theory of negated scalars, viz. Horn's A-I-E-O square?

Informally, one meaning refers to an action which has happened at least once before the reference time, and will not happen at any time after the reference time, and the other refers to an action which has not happened at any time before the reference time, but will happen at least once after the reference time.

Or, as I have thought about it now, it is a change between NOT(still(p)) and still(NOT(p)).

Comment: Commenting, not answering (as I don't have an answer), but you might be interested to know that "nid eto" in Welsh means both "not yet" and "not again". I'm afraid I have no idea when/how these senses of "eto" developed, but I could try to track down a copy of the Welsh Academy dictionary and look it up there, if you're interested?

Comment: @Berthilde Interesting! If the dictionary you have access to has etymological notes, I'd love to see what it says.